# Multiple threads for port scanning?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, networking, port

I wrote the following small script in python which scans for open tcp ports but it runs slow, I want to improve performance by using threads, how can I implement such feature?

```
socket.setdefaulttimeout(0.01)
    for port in range(0, 65536):
        s = None
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        if s.connect_ex((sys.argv[1], port)) == 0:
            open_ports.append(port)
        s.close()
```

I would like to set the number of threads via a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Since the python is one of the "slowest" languages and the operation that you'd like to perform is simple, i'd suggest you to use c lang or any other mid-low level languages. 
Multithreading to increase speed in a naturally slow language is just a futile effort, my opinion.

There're tons of examples online I'd suggest you to check
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85553/simple-c-port-scanner

Comment: The OP may have other reasons besides performance for using Python…

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in a function start_scan(port_range)

And Check the asyncio library:

```
asyncio.create_task(start_scan(port_range))
```

Then you can have a loop for the number of threads you want, and you create as much task as you want.
Then you await them one per one, or gather them.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

**======= EDIT =======**
To answer the question, how to split the range in sub list:

```py
import math

def split_ports(ports, threads):
    ports_per_threads = [[]]
    n_port_per_thread = math.ceil(len(ports)/threads)

    i = 0
    t = 0
    for p in ports:
        i+=1
        if (i > n_port_per_thread):
            i = 0
            t += 1
            ports_per_threads.append(list())
        ports_per_threads[t].append(p)

ports = range(100, 200)
ports_lists = split_ports(ports, 4)
```

That would give you this result :

```
ports = range(1, 9)
ports_lists = split_ports(ports, 4)
# -> [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
ports_lists = split_ports(ports, 2)
# -> [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
```

Comment: I don't want to create thread for each port...

Comment: No, you give a range of port. then you split it in the number of thread that you have.

Comment: how to do that? plus all threads add to same list...

Comment: @Ariel: Since the list will be a shared resource, you'll need to use a mutex Lock to control concurrent access to it.

Comment: not necessarily, all port take about the same time to scan, just split them before hand. you can iterate on them to seperate them in a lists of 2 dimensions. (1= threads, 2= ports)

Comment: @vinalti can you show example your code is very vague.... BTW I am taking the ports from a list (predefined) it's not clear at all how to split them... what if tomorrow I decided to change number of threads?

Comment: I edited the original post to include it, does it sounds clearer ?

Comment: Yes @vinalti, necessarily.

Comment: Please vote up my answer if you think it answers the question corretly, and @Ariel you can validate it, if it solves your problem. :)

Comment: Are you sure asyncio.create_task will make the program faster? Doesn't this just create concurrent tasks, which are scheduled using cooperative multi-tasking on a single CPU core/thread? To use multiple CPU cores/threads you need parallelism in addition to concurrency, so you need to use multiple hardware threads. See for example https://testdriven.io/blog/concurrency-parallelism-asyncio/

Comment: The limitation here it is not the CPU it is the network, so yes, it will make it faster. Because when you send a packet, you'll wait few seconds before to say that this port is closed. If you do it too early you may miss your packet, but during this time the CPU is just idle, waiting, so If he has something else to do he will do it, even on the same CPU core.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write something like:

```
import socket
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def check_socket(host, port):
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(0.01)
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        # return port if open, None otherwise
        return port if s.connect_ex((host, port)) == 0 else None


def main(host):
    with ThreadPool() as pool:
        result = pool.starmap(check_socket, ((host, port) for port in range(0, 65536)))
        # Pull out the list of open ports
        return [x for x in result if x is not None]
```